# Cassandra update table set column1 with column2 values

Tags: cassandra, cql, dml

I am trying to update table column1 values to be copied from column2 in same table in Cassandra.

I have tried these: but throwing error
**no viable alternative at input 'where' (...emp set col1_name = [shape] where...)**

```
UPDATE emp SETcol1_name = col2_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
UPDATE emp SET col1_name = select(col2_name) WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Yeah, Cassandra does not support subqueries; so you'll have to take another approach.